# Logging "Information" and/or Commenting?

Tags: c#, logging

I have written a Logger which writes into a local Text file. The Logger stores Information based on an indicator value in the App.Config and begins writing to files if the Value is higher than the indicator value. If the Indicator is 2, LogLevels 2,3,4 are Logged. Possible Flags are "Information", "Warning", "Exception", "Systemerror".

Now i have added pretty detailed Logging in the "Information" Level but forget to add comments. And when adding Comments i realized that all the "Information" Level Logging Info could aswell go as a comment.

The Question is: Is that okay? Can i just leave out Comments now? What would you do? What exactly is an "Information" in a log?

Comment: It is ok not adding comments, where they don't add any value.  Adding them for no reason, just increases code noise.  I would question however if you're perhaps logging too much information.  Do you really need to have all of those information logs?  Are they adding value?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look into the [log4net documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html) you can find that they use these kinds of log levels:

- ALL
- DEBUG
- INFO
- WARN
- ERROR
- FATAL
- OFF

And comparing this to your levels i think your *Comments* level is something like *Debug* and i think there is a difference between these two levels.